# Implementing Authentication using ADFS in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs

I am developing a website that should authenticate users using ADFS.
Basically, we have a CRM Dynamics deployed on a server, and the CRM Dynamics is having ADFS authentication.
Now, I am writing a .NET website that will target the CRM Dynamics and that .NET website will be available to public.

In order to implement authentication using ADFS, I read about **[this blog](http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/writing-custom-net-web-applications-for-dynamics-crm-2011/)**, but most of the information are unclear.

Anyone having an experience implementing ADFS authentication in ASP.NET site?

Any help on this much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: blog link does not provide any... link

Comment: sorry, I just have added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard workflow for a claims-enabled ASP.NET application.

e.g. [Building a test claims-aware ASP.NET application and integrating it with ADFS 2.0 Security Token Service (STS)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2011/06/27/building-a-test-claims-aware-asp-net-application-and-integrating-it-with-adfs-2-0-security-token-service-sts.aspx).

This uses VS 2010. In VS 2012, the same utility is called "Identity and Access Tool". In VS 2013, it's part of the project creation.

Basically:

- Create your application
- Add WIF as reference in .NET 3.5
- Update web.config using above utility
- Add your application as a Relying Party in ADFS

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but it may effect some security issues..
This is the way you can do..

1. Host your application in Static ip
2. Create users in your AD who and all are need to access the application from outside
3. Try to access from public
4. Ask the credential first time.

Dis adv: Security issues

Comment: what you say is something different than ADFS! you are saying is what we can achieve after hosting a web site by configuring it as Windows/ Integrated authentication and by setting domain and realm domain names... ADFS requires impersonating